# SQL - Show everything to Admin and show only one data to users

Tags: sql

**Edit:** Thanks prdp for the tip but I also need to show all franchises even if they don't have uses (Only the Admin, the Users should only see theirs)

I want to see all the avaible franchises as Admin but as an user only the one that belongs to me
I tried this sql query:

```
declare @BusinessRules_UserName varchar(80)
set @BusinessRules_UserName = 
/*-------------------------*/ 'admin'
/*---------------------*/ -- 'itt@ittijuana.edu.mx'
SELECT EMP_RFC
FROM Empresa
WHERE EMP_RFC = ( SELECT EmpresaUser_Empresa
                  FROM EmpresaUser
                  WHERE EmpresaUser_Email IN ( SELECT UserName
                                         FROM aspnet_Users
                                         WHERE @BusinessRules_UserName = UserName or @BusinessRules_UserName = 'admin'
                                        ));
```

When I search with an user account everything is ok, but when I use the admin one this appears:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 147
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Help, please

Comment: Replace `..EMP_RFC = (..` with `..EMP_RFC IN (..`

Comment: Or use `TOP 1` like `SELECT TOP 1  EmpresaUser_Empresa`

Comment: Whenever you suggest `TOP 1` don't miss to mention `ORDER BY`